# How to switch link every loop in selenium web driver python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im trying to get it to switch links every loop heres my original code

```
in_stock = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button'


def webscraper():


                web = webdriver.Chrome()
                web.get(line)
                read()
                time.sleep(1)
                try:

                    title = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1')
                    for post in title:
                        finale = (post.text)
                    price = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
                    for post in price:
                        cost = (post.text)

                    instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(in_stock).click()
                    james = (finale +"\n INSTOCK" + "   PRICE:  " + cost)
                    current_link = (web.current_url)
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    james = (finale +" \n OOS" + "   PRICE:  " + cost)
                    current_link = (web.current_url)
                web.quit()
                return (james, current_link)


now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

@bot.command()
async def startTarget(ctx):
    while True:
        result = await bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, webscraper)
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "PURCHASE",url = result[1] , color=0xbbff00)
        embed.set_author(name= "LINK")
        embed.set_thumbnail(
            url="https://www.target.com/p/call-of-duty-black-ops-cold-war-playstation-4/-/A-81321128")
        embed.add_field(name="ITEM:", value=result[0], inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Provided by KS0UR1#3062  TIME:"+ current_time)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        #await asyncio.sleep(10)
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

and I tried to add something like this

```
in_stock = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button'






def webscraper():
    filepath = 'tesxt.txt'
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
    while line:

                web = webdriver.Chrome()
                web.get(line.strip())
                line = fp.readline()
                time.sleep(1)
                try:

                    title = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1')
                    for post in title:
                        finale = (post.text)
                    price = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
                    for post in price:
                        cost = (post.text)

                    instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(in_stock).click()
                    james = (finale +"\n INSTOCK" + "   PRICE:  " + cost)
                    current_link = (web.current_url)
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    james = (finale +" \n OOS" + "   PRICE:  " + cost)
                    current_link = (web.current_url)
                web.quit()
                return (james, current_link)


now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

@bot.command()
async def startTarget(ctx):
    while True:
        result = await bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, webscraper)
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "PURCHASE",url = result[1] , color=0xbbff00)
        embed.set_author(name= "LINK")
        embed.set_thumbnail(
            url="https://www.target.com/p/call-of-duty-black-ops-cold-war-playstation-4/-/A-81321128")
        embed.add_field(name="ITEM:", value=result[0], inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Provided by KS0UR1#3062  TIME:"+ current_time)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

but it did not work and i got this error
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\test\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\test\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\test\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Use triple backquotes on a separate line around your code.

Comment: For looping through the lines in a file, the usual pattern is `with open(...) as fp:` then `for line in fp:`.